# How to append colors alternatives as chess board using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add colors to the divs `alternatively` as `chess board`

I have tried but its not working I have created it in jsfiddle could you please check it once what's wrong i had done here any help greatly appreciated thanks

[Here my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VP6UF/)

1. when i click on the chess button  i need to get colors as chessboard
2. when i clicked the clear button i should get the clear all the div
3. when i clicked the zebra button i should get the zebra format

Comment: are you allocating all your work to stack community ??

Comment: I think he tried but fail. It's not like he do nothing but asking

Comment: you didn't even take the effort to check the console for errors. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Not everyone knows the `console` object.

Comment: @NULL: what's this have to do with that object?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath `you didn't even take the effort to check the console for errors. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null` < queted you? - `Not everyone knows the console object.` > queted me - Meaning that not everyone knows about the webconsole and it's fetures.

Comment: @NULL: you don't have to know about that object (though it's *very* basic stuff), you just have to open the error console in your browser.. it looks like you just used wrong terminology.

Comment: it cost me 2 years to know "how to open error console"

Comment: sory guys thanks for reply don't mind  i need help

Comment: @KarolyHorvath When i referred to the `console`-object I thought that after reading your first comment that you would understand that I referred the usage of the console. But my bad I you got confused. Good we spend like 5 comment to clear op this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fixed:
http://jsfiddle.net/VP6UF/5/

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $(".box_a:even").css("background-color", "black");
    $(".box:odd").css("background-color", "black");
});
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("div > div > div").removeAttr('style');
});
$("#butn").click(function () {
    $("div > div > div:odd").css("background-color", "black");
});​
```

1. You are select wrong framework (mootools instead of jQuery)
2. Your code does not work with your current HTML. I changed a little bit to make it worked with minimum edit.

Comment: thanks alot mr.Bang Dao it's working nice coding thanks very much by2 by i didn't get about console object how to know abt wht is this could guide me how to know abt it thanks for my reply